# Ef6 Cast an Interface type to use as collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

Hello all I am trying to figure out how to do the following. I have many Entities that will use the following pattern and am not sure the best way to impalement it.

I will use dummy classes to demonstrate what i am trying to accomplish.
first thing is first we have methods that take an interface called `IClass`

```
public interface IClass
{
    string Title { get; set; }
    int Id { get; set; }
    ICollection<IPerson> People{get;set;}
}
public class StudentClass:IClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IPerson> People { get; set; }
}
public class TeacherClass : IClass
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<IPerson> People { get; set; }
}
public class Employee : IPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int EmployeeNumber { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
 public class Student : IPerson
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses { get; set; }
}
```

What I would like to do is use `modelBuilder` to register `ICollection<IPerson>` specific to that class. For example in the `TeacherClass` `IPerson` should be `Employee` and `StudentClass` it should be `Student`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why not simply let the `TeacherClass` have an `ICollection<Employee>`, and the `StudentClass` an `ICollection<Student>` ? Implement the `IClass` by using the employees or students collection.

Comment: This is all a mixture of persistence structure and business rule, where it should be persistence structure only.

Comment: so you're saying that it should be separate layers?

Comment: The logic decides what to store, persistence decides how to store